# SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'xxx'

Tags: php, libcurl

Ao tentar executar o curl no PHP me dá este erro..

> SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name
>   'xxx'

Gostaria de entender melhor isso, e até mesmo depurar o problema.

```
$arr["oi"] = "tchau";

 $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.xxx.com/teste/recebe_requisicao.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr);
        curl_exec($ch);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo json_encode($info);
```

No entanto, o retorno de *curl_getinfo* é este:

> "http_code":0

Tem outras variáveis também retornadas, mas não entendo qual delas é importante para verificar.

A requisição é feita de servidor para ele mesmo.. Veja que outros sites na mesma maquina não dão este erro.

---

**EDIT:**

Fiz testes usando o POSTMAN, e então a requisição funcionou.

Não entendo o porquê meu servidor fazer requisição para ele mesmo dá erro de SSL, no entanto o POSTMAN para ele fica OK.

Engraçado que outros sites do mesmo servidor estão OK, sem erro....

**EDIT 2**

Código gerado pelo POSTMAN, para usar no PHP com a livraria cURL

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.xxx.com/teste/recebe_requisicao.php",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "ola=valor",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Postman-Token: 70cfc5b2-fd30-4605-ae73-b96c5cae0a92",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

**EDIT 3**

Troquei o SSL Lets Encrypt por um Pago que eu já tinha, apenas para desencargo de consciência, mas pelo visto não resolveu..

Comment: Já desinstalei, instalei o SSL Lets Encrypt para verificar se isto não era o problema.

Comment: Talvez o ssl pode esta com problemas na configuração, você pode usar esse site ([ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)) para testar, verifique a informação `Chain issues`, Obs. nesse site você pode esconder os resultados marcando o `checkbox` **Do not show the results on the boards**. Outra coisa, como essa requisição é local não seria melhor usa `http://localhost/`

Comment: Por que você está fazendo uma requisição do servidor para ele mesmo? Não bastaria fazer um `require` ou até então executar o arquivo PHP pela função `exec`?

Comment: @IcaroMartins SSL está OK, o problema. O problema foi resolvido! E não era no SSL, porquê eu instalei e reinstalei umas 5 vezes(cpanel, lets encrypt e até 1 pago). Então falei com o administrador da Host, e parece que havia um problema de DNS interno(no arquivo hosts), então o ADM alterou para o IP do servidor(estava outro, nada a ver), e funcionou! Se algum de vocês conseguirem postar uma resposta ao caso, incluindo solucao #1: erro de SSL, e solução #2, erro de DNS com uma explicação plausível, será recompensado.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Sim poderia, e pouparia mais recursos(menos requisição), mas eu gosto de trabalhar desse jeito! Não compromete, não afeta, e se um dia eu notar que isso está consumindo, eu aperfeiçoo.

Answer (score 0):

Acrescenta mais essa opção:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

Comment: HTTP Code retornado é 502, na verdade, eu testei em produção isto antes, e deu erro de Bad Gateway(502) ao invés de retornar o erro mencionado no tópico.

Comment: Tenta usar o POSTMAN ou Insomnia para fazer esse teste. Depois você passa para o código.

Comment: Engraçado que utiliza o plugin RESTClient por exemplo(do firefox) e fazendo essa mesma requisição, funciona..

Comment: Então, faça o teste com esses programas. Lá ele gera até o código PHP pra você. Daí você vê o que tem de diferente.

Comment: Feitos os testes.. pelo PostMan deu OK, mas meu servidor requisitando para ele mesmo deu FAIL!! Ps: copiei o código pelo postman(em php-curl) e coloquei lá, o erro retornado é o mencionado no tópico "SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name"

Comment: Posta o código gerado pelo Postman.

Comment: Ok, editei no post e coloquei.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar as opções `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` e `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` juntas, ambas com valor `FALSE`. Deve resolver seu problema.

```
<?php

$arr["oi"] = "tchau";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.xxx.com/teste/recebe_requisicao.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // Primeira opção
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); // Segunda opção
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr);
curl_exec($ch);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo json_encode($info);

?>
```

Comment: Desabilitar o SSL não é bem uma solução, mas uma gambiarra, pois anula as vantagens do HTTPS, o que pode ser perigoso.

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente acontece quando o certificado não corresponde ao nome do host.

A solução seria entrar em contato com o host e solicitar que ele corrija seu certificado.
Caso contrário, você pode desativar a verificação do certificado pelo cURL, use a opção -k (ou --insecure).
Observe que, como a opção disse, é insegura. Você não deve usar esta opção na produção, pois ela permite certificados auto-assinados.

Mais informações podem ser [encontradas aqui](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html).

No seu caso, basta acrescentar isso em ambiente dev:

```
//suponho que vc tenha uma constante de ambiente... 
$app = APPLICATION_ENV;

$permission = ($app == 'production') ? true : false;

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.xxx.com/teste/recebe_requisicao.php",
  //acrescente aqui:::::::::::::: 
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => $permission,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => $permission,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "ola=valor",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Postman-Token: 70cfc5b2-fd30-4605-ae73-b96c5cae0a92",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce esta executando o PHP em no localhost?
caso sim, é necessario desabilitar o ssl. O SSL funciona na maquina local.
Porem o apache nao entende isso desse jeito. Adicione essas linhas na sessao do CURL.

```
[curl]
 O valor padrao para CURLOPT_CAINFO é necessario informar o caminho absoluto do 
 certificado.

 Onde "/Applications/AMPPS/extra/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem" é o caminho absoluto.
 Ou seja, é o local onde o arquivo cacert.pem esta salvo em sua distribuicao.
 Caso vc nao possua o AMPPS, e use o xaamp no windows. O caminho seria:

 Entao na url vc nao deve colocar a url do certifica e sim baixar o certificado
 no site: 


 curl.cainfo="/Applications/AMPPS/extra/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem"
 openssl.cafile="/Applications/AMPPS/extra/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem"
```